# if $a$ is a real number that $a\neq1$ and $a^5-a^3+a=2$,Prove $3<a^6<4$

Tags: inequality

> if $a$ is a real number that $a\neq1$ and $a^5-a^3+a=2$,Prove $3<a^6<4$

Things I have done: using AM-GM for $a\ge0$ $$a^5+a\ge2a^3$$

The equality occurs only in $a=1$ which is not true as we given $a\neq1$. so $$a^5+a=a^3+2>2a^3$$
thus, $4>a^6$ is true. I don't know how could I apply it to all real numbers and about $3<a^6$ I don't know what to do.Any hint or solutions is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: $a^5-a^3+a=2$ implies that $a\neq 1$, so why mentioning it apart?

Comment: @drhab. the author of question included it. maybe it is for emphasize in using it.

Comment: $a$ must be positive, because $a^4-a^2+1>0\;$ and $2=a^5-a^3+a=a(a^4-a^2+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a^5-a^3+a=a(a^4-a^2+1)$ so we multiply both sides of the original equation by $(a^2+1)$ and divide both sides by $a\neq 0$ to obtain $$a^6+1=\frac {2(a^2+1)}a$$ and use $a^2+1\gt 2a$ provided $a\neq 1$ - which may be where the condition came in.